# Control size and position of popup window in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this code that is opening a popup page.  I would like to control the size and position of the popup and I'm not sure how to change the code to do that.

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "newWindow", String.Format("<script>window.open('{0}');</script>", "/PopupPages/EmailPage.aspx"));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a list of options in the open method to specify size etc. See this [msdn article.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536651%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
window.open([url], null, [options]);
```

For example:

```
window.open("myURl.aspx", null, "height=200,width=400,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "newWindow", String.Format("<script>window.open('{0}', 'mywin', 'left=25, top=25, width=500, height=500');</script>", "/PopupPages/EmailPage.aspx"));
```

Answer (score 0):

here's what I got to work

```
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "newWindow", "<script>window.open('/PopupPages/EmailPage.aspx', '', 'top=100,left=300,menubar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,resizable=no,height=750,width=850,status=no,scrollbars=no,maximize=null,resizable=0,titlebar=no');</script>");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "OpenWindow", "window.open('Details.aspx','mywindow','menubar=1,resizable=1,width=900,height=600');", true);
```